# How to format this date 2021-11-14T18:30:00.000+00:00?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My ts file:

```
mydate: Date = new Date('2021-11-14T18:30:00.000+00:00');
```

I want in this format:-

```
07-July-2022
```

Plzz Help

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-string-to-date-object

Comment: As always could you indicate what you've tried so far

Comment: Answering questions like that basically just turns SO into a free coding service, which is not what it's for.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions about dates in JavaScript on this site. Please, do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: When parsing date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent), always make sure that the input conforms to the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ) — the parsing behavior with other formats is implementation-defined and may not work across all browsers. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. A library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated.

> Date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, while date-time strings (e.g. "1970-01-01T12:00") are treated as local. You are therefore also advised to make sure the input format is consistent between the two types.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

It is not recommended to parse strings like that with the Date object. You really should give a library a try. While moment.js was a popular choice in the past, I personally have a great experience with date-fns.

Docs: https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way is using the `day.js`

```js
dayjs("2022/07/07").format("DD-MMMM-YYYY")
```

Comment: moment.js is not recommended to use in new projects, even the developers themselves state that. https://momentjs.com/docs/
But have a look on the docs, they recommend a list otf alternatives.

Comment: Not to mention, even when they were maintaining the library, they explicitly said that you should give a format when parsing.

Comment: I just want to say that it is a lot easy using some library, not native Date API. Also I am not a fan of moment.js, in my projects I often use Ant.Design whose components are using moment.js, so I just write the first library I know at all

Comment: Changing the recommended lib only improves your answer halfway. If you provide code, then provide the code in full, which also includes the formatting to `07-July-2022`